# Terraform and ElasticBeanstalk. How do I mount a EFS in EC2 when EC2 is spun up by elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-efs

In short, we are using Terraform to manage our elasticbeanstalk environments. I need the ec2 being spun up by elasticbeanstalk to mount our EFS as well as subsequent EC2 must mount the same EFS when they are spun up by elasticbeanstalk.

I pursued the option of remote-exec, but cannot figure out how to use it in elasticbeanstalk. It seems I required an aws_instance to target the EC2 to execute the mount commands. This I do not have since beanstalk does that for me. None of the elasticbeanstalk settings I could find allows for mounting of an EFS or executing remote code in the EC2 either.

I was also searching for a potential config file solution where I can specify the mountings but no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Marcin with some luck I will be able to try and do this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use TF for that directly. Instead, you should use [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) for your application. Thus you would have to add `.ebextensions` to your application and provide code (bash script) that executes the mount operation, e.g. in [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands).

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate this approach.